# Ajax code is not working and returns Object Object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a pop-up form for registration on my site. And, I want to verify the email is not already in use prior to submitting. I am using "on submit" within there form to call validateForm. The call to validateForm works. IT even works when I don't have my Ajax call in the function. However, when I add my Ajax call, the Ajax continues to not work. It goes straight to error:  and I get Object Object. What is wrong with my Ajax portion that would keep it from working?  Could it be some setting on my host?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
        var email = document.forms["signupform"]["email"].value;
        if (email == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/CheckEmail2.php",
                data: {User_Email:email},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(resp)
                {
                    if (respects == "Found")
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert(data);

                }
            }); //end Ajax
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of `alert(data);` use `console.dir(data); ` what do you see in console?

Comment: Also do you see any 404 errors in console? What is respects is it resp or resp.respects?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see you have a logical statement using `respects` yet this is not defined anyplace. Did you mean `resp`?

Comment: Also, you are returning `true` or `false` to whom?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  The first argument to the error callback is the XHR object, which is why you are seeing the [Object object].  You need to read the API and examine the other arguments it is passing in.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what type of data is being returned. You indicate `text` in your code yet if it's `json`, that will change things.

Please test with the following code:

```
function validateForm(){
  var email = document.forms["signupform"]["email"].value;
  var result = false;
  if (email != ""){
    $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/CheckEmail2.php",  
      data: { "User_Email": email },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        if (resp != "Found"){
          result = true;
        }
      },
      error: function(data, status){
        console.log(data, status);
      }
    }); //end Ajax
  }
  return result;
}
```

When you test, you should see the results in the Console. It's also not clear how you plan to use your function, but I assume it needs to return `true` or `false`, so this must be done outside of the `$.ajax()` call.

I am not sure, but I would assume you would want to return `true` if `Found` is returned, yet this is not the logic you are using. So consider how you want that to work.

**Update**

I would advise the following in your PHP:

```
<?php
$search = array(
    "term" => "",
    "found" => false,
    "results" => ""
);
if(isset($_POST['User_Email'])){
    $search['term'] = $_POST['User_Email'];
    if(strpos($_POST['User_Email'], "@")){
        $search['found'] = true;
        $search['results'] = $_POST['User_Email'];
    }
}
header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($search);
?>
```

This will ensure that you are returning JSON data and will be easier to address in your AJAX code. Make a few changes like so:

```
function validateForm(){
  var email = document.forms["signupform"]["email"].value;
  var result = false;
  if (email != ""){
    $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/CheckEmail2.php",  
      data: { "User_Email": email },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        if(resp.found){
          result = true;
        }
      },
      error: function(data, status){
        console.log(data, status);
      }
    }); //end Ajax
  }
  return result;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thank you for your quick reply.  So right now for testing purposes, I have my CheckEmail2.php simply set as echo "Not Found";  once I can get that very simple line to work I will add back in my code to check my database for the email.  But even that way, I simply want to return either "Found" or "Not Found".  I tried your code and even with CheckEmail2.php set to echo "Not Found", result is not getting set to true.  Any more ideas?  My CheckEmail2.php file is in my same directory as my index.html file so that is why I have it set to "/CheckEmail.php". Should I lose the "/"?

Comment: @BPayne please clarify how the PHP is echoing "Not Found". What header is being used?

Comment: hey, so here is how my php file looks.     <?php
header("Content-type:application/json");
echo "Not Found";
?>                          I copied your code (validateForm) in and I still can get a true response.  Am I missing something simple.  How can I tell if it is even opening the php file?  my goal right now is just to get it to read my php file and return true

Comment: Yes, you must send Valid JSON response from PHP. Using `<?php header("Content-type:application/json"); echo "Not Found"; ?>` will not result in valid JSON data. This is why your AJAX is failing and it should not be set to "text" but to "json". What results do you see in your Console?

Comment: so I don't have a console.  Right now I am just using my free hosting site (Freehostia) text editor to edit and then just uploading and running my browser to check.  is this what my php return should look like?  echo json_encode("Not Found");

Comment: ok, I just changed the string in my checkemail2.php file and the error console log prints out the new string.  so that proves it is reading my php file but why will it never hit the success part??

Comment: Every web browser has a javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting data in JSON that is why you have to console.log to check instead of alert, `alert()` will not work and your ajax is working.

```
console.log(data);
```

use f12 to open Developer tools on your browsers and then you can check in it console tab.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21365613)

Comment: according to his question, this is a specific answer. He said, my ajax is not working, but his ajax is working because in an alert box he is getting Object Object. If he wants to see what he is getting back from ajax he needs to use console.log()  function to check data in the console. Alternatively, he can also check the response data by hitting f12 inside network tab.

Comment: The request is not returning json, as denoted by `dataType: 'text'` telling jQuery to leave the response as a string.  It is alerting Object Object because the first argument to the error callback is the XHR object.  This answer does not solve the issue, and is not accurate.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: ok, so I got my console open and it is dumping out "Not Found".    However, the console log that is printing is under the error: function...so it is hitting an error each time.  It never gets to the success console log.

Comment: @BPayne please update your code on the page CheckEmail2.php. I think the error is on the page CheckEmail2.php or its path.  You AJAX is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

you are receiving json object, change your datatype to "json" and then iterate through...
something like following

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "/CheckEmail2.php",
            data: {User_Email:email}, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
              if(data.results.length > 0) {
              for(i in data.results){
                var eachItem = data.results[i];
                var xxx = eachItem.xxx; // example
                console.log(xxx);
                .....
                ...
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
do I need this to call a query?  I mean I am calling it but just want to make sure that is right.  does my php need to change since I am using Json or is echo "Found"; still good?

Comment: Given that the OP explictily sets the `dataType: 'text'` to force jQuery to leave the response as a string, and the success method is comparing against the result as a string, why are you saying that he is returning json?

Comment: How else object object is being received if CheckEmail2.php is not returning json object.

Comment: ok, so I got my console open and it is dumping out "Not Found" which is the string in my php file. I can change the string and it dumps the new string in the console. So I know it is reading the file but why does it keep going to error function??. It never gets to the success console log.